# "Bookmark" other users favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I have been spending more time reading questions and answers rather than trying to gain rep points (which I am not really good at...).

One thing I have been doing recently is looking at highly reputable users and checking out their favorite questions.  It gives me a good insight into different technical areas, that I wouldn't normally stumble across.

What would be really good is that from a list fav users I have selected, I get updates when those users add new fav questions.

I think this feature would give a SO user more richer content in terms of learning and understanding questions posed and answered on SO.

Comment: (-1) for the reasons in my response.

Comment: I don't see a response, devin :)

Comment: @Jonathan: Can you hear me now? Is this thing on? *tap*tap*tap*

Answer (score 6):

Been requested before, in many forms. The consensus is that you should subscribe to their RSS feeds. If you only want their favorite questions, you can get those from:

https://stackoverflow.com/api/userfavorites.html?page=1&pagesize=1000&userId=54680&sort=Recent

or in json at

https://stackoverflow.com/api/userfavorites.json?page=1&pagesize=1000&userId=54680&sort=Recent

Comment: The RSS feeds are slightly different to my request.  I would like to pick which users I want to "watch" when they add new questions to their favs.

Answer (score 6):

Attempting to expand on [Ólafur's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19616/this-is-a-favourite-user-feature-request/19618#19618) excellent answer

The site is and was always designed not to be user-centric but rather 'content centric'. There are often requests that revolve around better ways to watch/interact with other users. However, these all detract from the purpose of the site: **Any user has the ability to provide the perfect answer.**

We don't want to encourage behaviour that would attach to a single user because it would basically detract from encouraging you to ask/answer questions in the normal way. If I follow Jon Skeet, it's very unlikely that I'm going to go through and find *better* answers to those questions. And, I'm taking time away from watching the main feed, where I might actually be able to contribute.

I occasionally go through some user's answers because I'm curious and I like their writing style, but I don't think we should be encouraging this behaviour through automation.

And, as mentioned, you can already subscribe to an RSS feed.

Comment: Your answers are always excellent. You're much more succinct that I am. I try to use as many words as possible.

Comment: I think the request is for a specific piece of functionality, that will help developers improve learn, whilst using SO.  The discussion here seems to be going slightly of tangent.

The feature is to see question others users are adding to their favorites.  So, in a way, a SO user is "bubbling" up "content" that they feel is important to them.  Just another way of gathering valuable information from SO.  

This discussions here seems to be typical of what happens with software features/requirements.  Scope Creep...

Comment: However, my point, although tangential, still stands. We should not be concentrating on highlighting which questions some user favorites. The information is available, yes, but it is not the core functionality of the site. We are not supposed to be concentrating on what a certain user thinks.

Comment: Agreed! I was also thinking that I should be able to follow a user.  But as said by @devinb I agree that every one has his/her own interests and favorite questions they would like to see later or follow updates on. But for example if someone is interested in interest area of Jon Skeet, better they go to Jon Skeets' blog or follow him on twitter or other Social sites. stackoverflow is not a good site for it.

Answer (score 2):

This could fall into the "SO is not a social site" pit. But I think there are many things that could be done to improve the functionality of the "fav" feature.